# Iran Visa Issue: U.S. - Mexico Dual National Residing in EU

Tags: usa, dual-nationality, eu, iran, tehran

Several months ago I tried going to Iran with my American passport to attend a marathon but got denied. The embassy or company didn't give me any direct reason as to why but shortly afterwards the marathon's date was moved (which I suspect was the reason I was denied). I plan on trying to go again using my Mexican passport by using the Visa on Arrival but my circumstances will be a bit different.

For the next few years I will live & work in the EU. My residence permit will be based on my American passport since I didn't get my other one until after submitting my EU paperwork. I assume I will need to use my former passport to exit/enter the EU but want to use the latter to enter Iran. The biggest problem I foresee would be arriving at IKIA from an EU flight without entry/exit stamps from the country I'm arriving. What issues could this cause, if any?

I understand how to travel with multiple passports but haven't seen anyone post or comment about a similar situation of having dual citizenship but residing in a third country and wanting to travel to a fourth one in which one citizenship might cause issues. The closest I've found are below:

[Travelling to Iran with two passports, including one US passport [duplicate]](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74706/travelling-to-iran-with-two-passports-including-one-us-passport)

[Visiting Iran as a dual EU-American citizen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82140/visiting-iran-as-a-dual-eu-american-citizen)

[Alone in Iran - What was I Thinking?](https://www.heartmybackpack.com/blog/backpacking-solo-through-iran/)

[Anna Everywhere: Backpacking in Iran](http://annaeverywhere.com/backpacking-in-iran/)

Comment: We have a comprehensive answer about this already. Please take a few minutes to read it, and click the button "This solved my problem" if it answers your question, or edit your question to add any specific points you are not sure about after reading it.